# is it ok to pass async function where non async function needed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, callback

as below, an async function was given for a paramter where non-async function expected, but it worked, why?

```js
function getCallback(param, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback && callback(param);
  }, 1);
}

getCallback(13, async (param) => {
  console.log(param);
});

---
13
```

Comment: Because both `async function` expressions and `function` expressiona create callable function objects ... Why did you expect it not to work?

Comment: `getCallback` doesn't do anything with the return value of `callback`, so it is unaffected whether `callback` returns a promise or not. And returning a promise is pretty much the only distinguishing feature of an `async` function when viewed from the outside.

Comment: Well if your callback returns something ir matters.  Eg, if the callback expected a number, it would'nt work etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It worked, why?

Because an `async` function is just a function that returns a promise and can be called like any other function. Your `getCallback` ignores the return value of `callback()`, so it doesn't matter what it returns.

> Is it ok to pass `async` function where no `async` function is needed?

No, it generally is not ok to pass an `async` function (or another function that returns a promise) to a function that doesn't expect the callback to return a promise. Promises should not be ignored, they should be `.then()`-chained or `await`ed, and they need special error handling. If the `getCallback` does not handle (promise) errors, you must not pass a callback that errors.

Comment: thanks~ I assumed that 'async' is kind of builder which return an object like python.